# Finding lowest average grade difference

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Given a class with n boys and n girls, in which the girls recieved the grades p1,...,pn, and the boys recieved the grades s1,...,sn in an exam, find a pairing of girl-boy in a way that minimizes the average difference between the grades in the couples.
For example, if p1=30, p2=60, s1=50, s2=90, we should pair girl #1 with boy #1 (20 points difference) and girl #2 with boy #2 (30 points difference), and we will get a minimal average difference of (30+20)/2 = 25.

Prove that the following algorithm is optimal:
Pair the girl with the lowest grade to the boy with the lowest grade. Then pair the girl with the second lowest grade to the boy with the second lowest grade, etc.

---

In my solution, I tried using the greedy choice property (showing that there exist an optimal solution where a certain element is in the solution, and then using induction to prove that all elements are in the optimal solution) :

Let A1<=...<=An be the girl's grades sorted, and B1<=...<=Bn be the boys' grades sorted.

Claim - There exists an optimal solution which includes the pair A1-B1 (the boy with the lowest grade paired to the girl with the lowest grade).

Proof - Assume by contradiction that the statement is false. Therefore, no optimal solution includes A1-B1 as a pair. Assume A1-Bi (i>1) and B1-Aj (j>1) are pairs in the solution. We know that A1<=Aj and B1<=Bi. How do I continue from here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Therefore the difference between S1 and P1 is smaller than the difference between Sj and P1...*". This is flawed. If `S=[1,10], P=[10,20]`, then `|S2-P1| < |S1-P1|`.

Comment: If this helps any, you're minimizing the difference of two vectors under the L1 norm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm If you ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com/ you're sure to get a fast answer.

Comment: I second Matt's suggestion. I think you will get faster answers on math.stackexchange and they will probably be higher quality for this kind of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found something based on some geometric observations.
Say you have only 4 numbers for now: a1 <= a2 and b1 <= b2 (0).

|a1-b1| + |a2-b2| <= |a1-b2| + |a2-b1|   (1)

In this case, we want to check if (1) is true.

I rewrite (1) based on obvious equivalence relations:

( |a1-b1| + |a2-b2| ) ^ 2 <= ( |a1-b2| + |a2-b1| ) ^ 2 (2)

-2 * a1 * b1 -2 * a2 * b2 <= -2 * a1 * b2 -2 * a2 * b1 (3)

Should I explain how I got from (2) to (3)? I guess not.

Then we get:

a1*b1 + a2*b2 >= a1*b2 + a2*b1 (4)

a1(b1-b2) >= a2*(b1-b2) (5)

a1(b1-b2) - a2*(b1-b2) >=0 (6)

a1(b1-b2) + a2*(b2-b1) >=0 (7)

But (5) is obviously true because b1-b2 <= 0 and a1 <= a2 (see (0)).

This is a rigorous proof for N=2.

My gut tells me this should be generalized somehow 
pretty easily for the case of N. Maybe we can try an
induction from here (having seen these (1),(2),(3), etc.).

Geometrically, you can imagine that Ai and Bj as points
on two parallel numeric linex (axis A, axis B). One 
pairing configuration is defined by connecting the paired
points from A and B with segments. Your statement basically 
says that the optimal pairing is the one in which no two
segments (Ai,Bj) cross each other (they may overlap with 
each other /in the optimal solution/ but may not cross each other).
Right?

Now, if we do the same thing (which I did for N=2),
for any N, you will get this question: "Is 
a1(b1-bi1) + a2(b2-bi2) + a3(b3-bi3) + ... + aN*(bN-biN) >= 0  (4') 
true", where i1,i2,...,iN is any permutation of (1,2,...,N), 
and given that a[i] <= a[i+1] and b[i] <= b[i+1] for each i.

Now, here we do induction on N to prove (4').
Suppose (4') is true for N and for all K such that K<N.
Add two more numbers to A and B. Say aN+1 and bN+1.
Let's say they get inserted at positions s1 (in A) and s2 (in B)
in their respective SORTED sequences (A, B). Let's say s1 <= s2
(the reverse case is analogical). So now as1 = aN+1 and bs2 = bN+1,
but s1 and s2 are their real indices in the NEW sorted sequences.

But now proving (4') for N+1 turns into a matter of 
proving it for N=2 because only these terms (from (4'))  
matter when we do the step from N to N+1.

as1 * (bs1 - bs2) + as2 * (bs2 - bs1) >= 0 (7') 
and as we saw this is true for N=2 (see (7) above).

For the other N-1 terms (which remain from (4')), we get that the 
inequality (4') is true due to the assumption from the induction (that it is 
true for N-1). Thus from the truth for 2 and N-1 we got the truth for N+1.
Hope you understand how I did it. On paper it is easier 
to write it, hard to write it here.

So this should be your rigorous proof for the N case.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Say we have:

P1<=P2<=...<=Pn, 
and 
S1<=S2<=...<=Sn.

Let's assume that this statement is not true,
and there's another optimal solution.
This means we assume P1 is paired with Sk, where k>1 in that solution.

Now let's take a look at that Pj which is paired with S1 (if you draw 
it as a graph, these two lines P1-Sk and Pj-S1 would cross each other).

So I am interested in the first two lines which cross each other.

Now think what happens if we take that same configuration but we change 
it by pairing P1 with S1 and Pj with Sk. The sum will decrease
(or it could stay the same if P1 = Pj or S1 = Sk).

Example:
1 3 5 7 100 150
2 4 6 8 120 120

But if it stays the same we can move on ahead in the two sequences.

So it turned out that our optimal solution is not optimal.
This is contradiction so our assumption is not correct.

Note 1: Actually in my proof I should be saying not P1,
but the Pm with smallest m, such that Pm is not paired with Sm
but with some Sk where k>m.
I've said P1 here just for simplicity.

Note 2: To prove this part:
*"Now think what happens if take that same configuration but 
instead we pair P1 with S1 and Pj with Sk. The sum will decrease."*
just think what happens if you have 4 numbers only
P1 <= P2
S1 <= S2

Then should you pair them: P1-S1 and P2-S2 or crossed-over like 
P1-S2 and S1-P2. Here a few different cases need to be worked out.

1 1 (couple 1 - equal numbers)
2 2 (couple 2 - also equal numbers)

1 3 (different numbers)
2 2 (equal numbers)

1 5 (different numbers)
2 10 (different numbers)

Note 3: OK, I think some boundary cases and details should
be worked out :) but basically this idea should work.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Your answer is a great explanation but it is not a proof. I edited my post with the beginning of the proof. Maybe you know how to continue from there ?

Comment: I also thought of using mathematical induction but didn't find a way to make the step from N to N+1. How would you do that? So, suppose it is true for N, how to you step to prove it is true for N+1? I will think some more today, I like this problem :)

Comment: @amitooshacham I proved it in a different way. See my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Observe that: 
- no matter how you arrange the pairs, the sums of each set will be constant, and so will be the difference between the two sums. 
- the 'sum of differences' can only be equal or greater than the 'difference of sums'
```

So what is that makes the 'sum of differences' greater than the 'difference of sums'?

```
This is how I would structure the proof:
1) what you want to prove is that sorting minimizes the cases that make the 'sum of differences' greater.
2) what can make the 'sum of differences' greater than the 'difference of sums' are the pairs where the size relation is opposite to the size relation of the sums. For example, if in your sample the sum of all the P grades is greater than the sum of all the S grades (sumP > sumS), any pair where p < s.
3) Now, all you have to prove is that any non-sorted arrangement can only make things worse.

(Forgive the absence of proper math language and depth, I have an excuse for the first though, I'm new to SO and still trying to master the editor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying find minimal average difference. So what is average difference: 1/n * ((p1-s1)+(p2-s2)+...+(pn-sn)) it is 1/n * ((p1+p2+..+pn) - (s1+s2+..+sn)) which doesn't seem depend on ordering. Well you can sort it and pair and it will have minimal average distance as well as any other ordering.

Comment: No, he's trying to minimize the sum of the paired distances' absolute values |Ai-Bj| and not the sum of the paired distances' values Ai-Bj. This is how I got it.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Can you point the place where this is mentioned in question?

Comment: You're right. It is not mentioned explicitly. It is self-understood from a few things which I believe you noticed.